# Webmatrix - Persisting query strings across pages

Tags: jquery, razor, webmatrix

I've just finished setting up pagination on one of my search pages, but i'm having issues because the query-strings (that i use to build my search query) are lost when i click between pages. Is there an easy method of persisting them, or will i need to write some fancy javascript to do this?

For example, i might have a page with the following URL localhost\search?qstring1=1&qstring2=2

At the bottom of the page, i have the following code, which provides links to where i need to persist these query strings.

```
for (var i = 1; i < totalPages + 1; i++){
    <li><a href="/search1/@i">@i</a></li>
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get access to the current query string with `Request.QueryString`. Something like this ought to do the trick:

```
for (var i = 1; i < totalPages + 1; i++) {
    <li><a href="/search/@i?@Request.QueryString">@i</a></li>
}
```

Your links should then end up looking like this:

```
/search?x=1&y=2
/search/2?x=1&y=2
/search/15?x=1&y=2
```

`UrlData[0].AsInt(1)` should have your page number which defaults to page one, and your query string should persist.

Comment: exactly what i wanted! epic answer.

Comment: If i don't have any query-strings added, it still adds the ? to the next page, but not a huge deal, I'm just picky :p

Comment: `<li><a href="/search/@i@(Request.QueryString.ToString().Length == 0 ? null : "?" + Request.QueryString)">@i</a></li>`

Comment: That's still adding the ? for some reason.

Comment: It will persist a `?` on its own if it gets on there somehow, but it won't add one itself - just tested it to be sure. You could change the way it works to actually remove an empty query string if you liked though (test against `Length < 2` or similar).

Comment: ah, my bad! i had a cheeky ? hiding in my code. Works an absolute treat! I know i'm picky, but i just love clean code! :)

Comment: Cleanliness is absolutely next to godliness for programmers.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using some querystring builder if you want to do it in managed code. Where you can access the current page querystring add/remove key/value pairs from it based on different links on the page. Please check one solution here:http://weblogs.asp.net/bradvincent/archive/2008/10/27/helper-class-querystring-builder-chainable.aspx

e.g:

```
//create a querystring from the current URL, add 'id','user' and 'sessionId' values and remove an 'action' value
//output : "?id=123&user=brad&sessionId=ABC"
string strQuery = QueryString.Current.Add("id", "123").Add("user", "brad").Add("sessionId", "ABC").Remove("action").ToString();
```